# MongodDB "uncaught exception: SyntaxError: illegal character : @(shell):1:19"

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, syntax-error, git-bash

- MongoDB v4.4
- GitBash v2.31.1
- Windows10

First of all, i'm running my mongo shell through Git Bash.
I'm just starting to learn mongodb.
Ok, now adressing the problem.
After running mongod in the background, i run mongo on another terminal.
So, commands like "**show dbs**","**use *database***" works fine but when i try to "**db.*database*.insertOne( {*property: "exampletext"*})**" into a collection. It returns me with the given error i.e. **uncaught exception: SyntaxError: illegal character :
@(shell):1:19**

**BUT!!!!** get this,
If i do the exact same thing on my mongo terminal located at c:\programfiles\mongodb\server\4.4\bin\mongo.exe

I have not a clue as to what is happening and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I'm very new to the tech world so getting very technical might make me crazy. Help would be appreciated. And also knowledge as to why it's not working would be nice.